# How can I run a T-test on Panel Data in Stata?

Tags: dataset, panel, stata

I have a panel dataset of treatment group and control. I would like to test the means for this panel. How can I proceed? Also my panel is unbalanced, what does this mean and how will this affect my results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is barely on-topic here. The easiest thing to do would be to fit a FE panel regression model and test that the coefficient on treatment is zero. Here's an example:

```
webuse nlswork
xtset idcode
xtreg ln_w i.south, fe vce(robust)
test 1.south
```

Your other questions are off-topic here since they are about statistics and not about programming. You can try Crossvalidated SE site or Statalist.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a separate site for statistics questions.